# Entity framework: Database first/Code first hybrid

Tags: entity-framework, database-first

I am trying to create a custom Entity Framework (4.2) entity that would be mapped to my database like it would be done in a Code first approach.

The issue is that my entity framework data model is using Database first.

How can I add my custom entity to entity framework's context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by the Database first you mean that you already have EDMX created from exiting database you simply cannot use code first. You must create table and update model (EDMX) from the database to include it in EDMX.

**Edit based on comment:**

> I want to create a BriefUser entity that would basically be a lighter
>   version of User but it would have properties retrieved from User's
>   foreign keys.

Well this is possible. You can either create BriefUser as common class and use projection in query.

```
var breifUser = (from x in context.Users
                 where ...
                 select new BriefUser
                 {
                     // Fill BreifUser's properties here
                 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can even refactor former code to reusable extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<BriefUser> ProjectUser(this IQueryable<User> query)
{
    return query.Select(x => new BreifUser() 
                             { // Fill BreifUser's properties here });
}
```

and use it like:

```
var briefUser = context.Users.ProjectUser().FirstOrDefault(...);
```

It is also possible to define your new class as "entity view". The first problem is that each table can be mapped to only one entity (except some advanced concepts like inheritance or splitting) so you cannot define your BriefUser as a new entity type because mapping both `User` and `BriefUser` to `UserTbl` would violate this rule. You must use special construct called [QueryView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716798.aspx).

`QueryView` is view in mapping level. It allows you to create new mapped type which is projection of existing mapped entities defined directly in EDMX's MSL part. The projection is defined as custom Entity SQL query. The problem is that `QueryView` has limitations:

- It doesn't offer all Entity SQL features - for example it doesn't support aggregations (which I consider as really missing feature). Without aggregations you for example cannot create a new type which will contain property counting some related entities.
- It is not supported in designer. You must edit your EDMX as XML to define `QueryView` and you must write Entity SQL query yourselves.
- Resulting type is a "view" and it is read-only.

> I want to keep the EDMX file, but also be able to add an entity
>   (BriefUser) to EF's context.

This is not possible. Your `BreifUser` is only projection / view and EF is not able to track changes back to originating tables so you cannot add `BreifUser` to context and persist it. In case of `QueryView` you can achieve it if you define custom stored procedures which will no how to decompose `BreifUser` and modify all related tables. These stored procedures must be imported to the EDMX and mapped to data modification operations of the view entity. Btw. same will happen if you map your entity to the database view because EF takes all views as read-only.

Comment: Yeah, I do have the EDMX. So I *have to* have a table (or view) for each entities in my data model? I can't just have an object with properties that map to other entities' properties (so it's still in EF's context).

Comment: I'm sorry. I probably didn't understand your question. So what do you really want to do?

Comment: Let's say that I have a `UserTbl` table in my database.
This `UserTbl` table is mapped to an EF entity (`User`) in my EDMX file.
I want to create a `BriefUser` entity that would basically be a lighter version of `User` but it would have properties retrieved from `User`'s foreign keys.
I want to keep the EDMX file, but also be able to add an entity (`BriefUser`) to EF's context. So basically `BriefUser` and `User` would be mapped to the same data. -- I would like to be able to do this without creating a table or a view in the database.